# multiprocessing Python Kafka consumer client not getting back messages

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-multiprocessing, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-kafka-python

a Python consumer client worked fine when ran as standalone but not able to retrieve message when run as a multiprocessing worker with same configuration.

The clients always print the message in the block where it get None for msg.
Really appreciate any help in diagnosing this issue.

The worker basically looks like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
...
class saListener(Process):
     def   __init__(self, n)
            self.ClientName = "saListener-" + str(n)
            ...
            schema_registry_client = SchemaRegistryClient(schema_registry_conf)
            value_avro_deserializer = AvroDeserializer(ccloud_lib.value_schema, schema_registry_client)
            conf["value.deserializer"] = value_avro_deserializer
            self.cons = DeserializingConsumer(conf)
            Process.__init__(self)

    def connect(self):
            self.cons.subscribe([self.topic])

    def run(self):
            while True:
                            msg = self.cons.poll(5.0)
                            if msg is None:
                                    print(self.ClientName + ":Waiting for message or event/error in poll()")
```

The controller look like:

```
for n in range(instances):
                lnr_instance = saListener(n)
                lnr_instance.connect()
                lnr_instance.start()
```

Client configuration:

```
   "bootstrap.servers" : "srv1:909,srv2:909",
   "group.id" : "ainvil9_intraday_group",
   "debug" : "all",
   "max.poll.interval.ms" : "30000",
   "enable.auto.commit" : "true",
   "fetch.wait.max.ms" : "1000",
   "session.timeout.ms" : "10000",
   "auto.commit.interval.ms" : "500",
   "sasl.mechanism" : "GSSAPI",
   "security.protocol" : "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
   "sasl.kerberos.service.name" : "kafka",
   "ssl.ca.location" : "security/ca.cert.pem",
   "sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd" : "kinit -R -p -kt security/kafka_ist_producer.keytab kafka_ist_producer@DMS",
   "sasl.kerberos.keytab" : "security/kafka_ist_producer.keytab",
   "sasl.kerberos.principal" : "kafka_ist_producer@DMS"
```

It looked like the consumers as multiprocessing workers were not able get a offset:

```
%7|1596766163.070|HEARTBEAT|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:main]: GroupCoordinator/9: Heartbeat for group "ainvil9_intraday_group" generation id 1
 %7|1596766163.070|COMMIT|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:main]: OffsetCommit for -1 partition(s): cgrp auto commit timer: returned: Local: No offset stored
 %7|1596766163.070|UNASSIGN|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:main]: Group "ainvil9_intraday_group": unassign done in state up (join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb): without new assignment: OffsetCommit done (__NO_OFFSET)
 %7|1596766163.070|SEND|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/9: Sent HeartbeatRequest (v3, 97 bytes @ 0, CorrId 12)
 %7|1596766163.070|SEND|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/9: Sent HeartbeatRequest (v3, 97 bytes @ 0, CorrId 12)
 %7|1596766163.073|RECV|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/9: Received HeartbeatResponse (v3, 6 bytes, CorrId 12, rtt 3.03ms)
 %7|1596766163.073|RECV|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:GroupCoordinator]: GroupCoordinator/9: Received HeartbeatResponse (v3, 6 bytes, CorrId 12, rtt 3.08ms)
 %7|1596766163.181|COMMIT|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:main]: OffsetCommit for -1 partition(s): cgrp auto commit timer: returned: Local: No offset stored
 %7|1596766163.181|UNASSIGN|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:main]: Group "ainvil9_intraday_group": unassign done in state up (join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb): without new assignment: OffsetCommit done (__NO_OFFSET)
 %7|1596766163.573|COMMIT|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: OffsetCommit for -1 partition(s): cgrp auto commit timer: returned: Local: No offset stored
 %7|1596766163.573|COMMIT|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:main]: OffsetCommit for -1 partition(s): cgrp auto commit timer: returned: Local: No offset stored
 %7|1596766163.573|COMMIT|rdkafka#consumer-4| [thrd:main]: OffsetCommit for -1 partition(s): cgrp auto commit timer: returned: Local: No offset stored
 %7|1596766163.573|UNASSIGN|rdkafka#consumer-4| [thrd:main]: Group "ainvil9_intraday_group": unassign done in state up (join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb): without new assignment: OffsetCommit done (__NO_OFFSET)
 %7|1596766163.573|UNASSIGN|rdkafka#consumer-2| [thrd:main]: Group "ainvil9_intraday_group": unassign done in state up (join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb): without new assignment: OffsetCommit done (__NO_OFFSET)
 %7|1596766163.573|UNASSIGN|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: Group "ainvil9_intraday_group": unassign done in state up (join state wait-assign-rebalance_cb): without new assignment: OffsetCommit done (__NO_OFFSET)
 %7|1596766163.682|COMMIT|rdkafka#consumer-3| [thrd:main]: OffsetCommit for -1 partition(s): cgrp auto commit timer: returned: Local: No offset stored
```

Comment: Code looks okay to me, can you share your consumer conf as well? Also, when the consumer starts, does it show the partitions it gets assigned to consume from?

Comment: Edited post and added conf details. Thanks.